# Does anybody know how to choose the data model when using impala?

Tags: performance, hadoop, hbase, impala

There several kind of file format like impala internal table or external table format like csv, parquet, hbase. Now we need to guarantee the average insert rate is 50K row/s and each row is about 1K. And, some of the data also can be updated occasionally. We also need to do some aggregation operation on those data.

I think Hbase is not a good choose for large aggregation compute when using impala with external table. Does anybody have suggestion about it?

Thanks, Chen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never worked with Impala, but I can tell you a few things based on my experience with Hive.

HBase will be faster if you have a good key design and a proper schema, because just like with Hive, Impala will translate your WHERE into scan filters, it'll depend a lot on the type of queries you run. There are multiple techniques to reduce the amount of data read by a job: from simple ones like providing start and stop rowkeys, timeranges, reading only some families/columns, the already mentioned filters... to more complex like solutions like performing realtime aggregations on your data (*) and keeping them as counters.

Regarding your insert rate, it can perfectly handle it with the proper infrastructure (better to use the HBase native JAVA API), also, you can buffer your writes to get even better performance.

*Not sure if Impala supports HBase counters.

Comment: That's very perfect suggestion. We'll try to re-design the key based on our scenario. By the way, we have try the buffer, it can dramatically improve the insert performance. Very appreciated for your help!

Comment: Glad to help, when planning your keys just keep in mind that sequential row keys could cause region hotspotting issues (Take a look at this: http://blog.sematext.com/2012/04/09/hbasewd-avoid-regionserver-hotspotting-despite-writing-records-with-sequential-keys/). Please consider accepting the answer if it has solved your question :)

Comment: BTW, just ran a few HIVE queries this weekend (full table scans), read performance from HBase was +500000 req/sec per region server with a 50k scanner cache size. In Impala, cache size can be set with the "HBASE_CACHING" query option.